# pip upgrade problem with TLS/SSL on WLS Debian

Tags: python-3.x, pip, debian, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I try to upgrade my pip via *sudo python3.10 -m pip install --upgrade pip*

But I cant get a connection via https cause of some ssl errors..
I found many different solutions but not for my configuration.

I need pip >= 3.6 :/

I work on a WSL Debian:

```
@LAPTOP-E5BVUDKC:~/Python-3.10.6$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 9.13 (stretch)
Release:        9.13
Codename:       stretch

@LAPTOP-E5BVUDKC:~/Python-3.10.6$ pip -V
pip 20.3.4 from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip (python 3.5)

@LAPTOP-E5BVUDKC:~/Python-3.10.6$ python3 --version
Python 3.5.3
```

My error msg:

```
@LAPTOP-E5BVUDKC:~/Python-3.10.6$ sudo curl -sS https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3.10
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pip
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.
```

Answer (score 1):

Run the following commands in your WSL terminal for Python3.9

1. Update package lists

   sudo apt update
2. Install dependent libraries

   sudo apt install build-essential zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libgdbm-dev libnss3-dev libssl-dev libsqlite3-dev libreadline-dev libffi-dev curl libbz2-dev
3. Download Python binary package

   wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.9.1/Python-3.9.1.tgz
4. Unzip the package

   tar -xzf Python-3.9.1.tgz
5. Execute configure script

   cd Python-3.9.1
   ./configure --enable-optimizations
6. Build Python 3.9

   make -j 2
7. Install Python 3.9

   sudo make install